# How to get the domain in a variable?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm running multiple codes with different domains. I do not want to put the domain manually.
For example:
`var domainName = 'domain.com.br';`

I would like to know if it is possible to get the domain (G Suite) through a variable.
For example:
`var domainName = get.domain ();`

Comment: [Have you look in 'Admin SDK Directory Service'?](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` / `Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()` to get the active/effective user email address  and JavaScript string handling techniques like using regular expressions:

```
 var domain = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail().match('\@(.*)$')[1]
```

Validation of regex expression

```js
var match = 'useraname@example.com'.match('\@(.*)$');
console.info(match[1])
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!
Worked perfectly

Comment: @LucasBorges I'm glad that you found my answer helpful to you. Please checkout [What should I do when someone answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/somenone-answers)